# How to convert values to N bits of resolution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random, precision

My computer uses 32 bits of resolution as default. I'm writing a script that involves taking measurements with a multimeter that has N bits of resolution. How do I convert the values to that?

For example, if I have a RNG that gives 1000 values

```
nums = randn(1,1000);
```

and I use an N-bit multimeter to read those values, how would I get the values to reflect that?

I currently have

```
meas = round(nums,N-1);
```

but it's giving me N digits, not N bits. The original random numbers are unbounded, but the resolution of the multimeter is the limitation; how to implement the limitation is what I'm looking for.

Edit I: I'm talking about the resolution of measurement, not the bounds of the numbers. The original values are unbounded. The accuracy of the measured values should be limited by the resolution.

Edit II: I revised the question to try to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Does [`single`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) (e.g. `single(nums)`) produce the arithmetic you're looking for?

Comment: `randn(n,1)'` is the same as `randn(1,n)`. Why transpose?

Comment: Regarding your edit: (1) Please leave a comment under answers that you find don’t answer your question. That gives people a chance to revisit their answer. (2) It is now not at all clear what you are asking. Please revise your question to explain your problem in more detail. It looks like the instrument you want to simulate uses floating-point numbers? How is that even possible? I don’t know any instrument that doesn’t have bounds to the values it can measure.

Comment: If you are talking about floating-point, is [this](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/05/08/half-precision-16-bit-floating-point-arithmetic/) what you’re looking for?

Answer (score 1):

`randn` doesn’t produce bounded numbers. Let’s say you are producing 32-bit integers instead:

```
mums = randi([0,2^32-1],1,n);
```

To drop the bottom `32-N` bits, simply divide by an appropriate value and round (or take the floor):

```
nums = round(nums/(2^(32-N)));
```

Do note that we only use floating-point arithmetic here, numbers are integer-valued, but not actually integers. You can do a similar operation using actual integers if you need that.

Also, obviously, N should be lower than 32. You cannot invent new bits. If N is larger, the code above will add zero bits at the bottom of the number.

Comment: The idea is, there are two sources generating unbounded random numbers (i.e. no maximum integer value), and a third party is using a multimeter with N bits of resolution to measure those values; because the multimeter has a min/max integer value, the measurements may or may not be accurate. What I'm having trouble with is setting up the code such that the multimeter is measuring those numbers but with the limitation of bits of resolution and how to implement those bits.

Answer (score 0):

With a multimeter, it is likely that the range is something like -M V to M V with a a constant resolution, and you can configure the M selecting the range.

This is fixed point math. My answer will not use it because I don't have the toolbox available, if you have it you could use it to have simpler code.

You can generate the integer values with the intended resolution, then rescale it to the intended range.

```
F=2^N-1 %Maximum integer value
X=randi([0,F],100,1)
X*2*M/F-M %Rescale, divide by the integer range, multiply by the intended range. Then offset by intended minimum.
```

Comment: The idea is, there are two sources generating unbounded random numbers (i.e. no maximum integer value), and a third party is using a multimeter with N bits of resolution to measure those values; because the multimeter has a min/max integer value, the measurements may or may not be accurate. What I'm having trouble with is setting up the code such that the multimeter is measuring those numbers but with the limitation of bits of resolution and how to implement those bits.